# wildfly 10 multiple instances (offsets) but one listener port

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, war, wildfly-10

I have issues with port offsets I am using locally installed wildfly 10 without any explicit configs.

The thing is, once I deploy three different war files with three different port offsets, the latest instance/port accepts all the requests for all war files.

Why is that so?

for example:

```
localhost:8100/war1/helloworld -> not working
localhost:8200/war2/helloworld -> not working

localhost:8300/war1/helloworld -> works
localhost:8300/war2/helloworld -> works
localhost:8300/war3/helloworld -> works
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to provide three different applications (wars) on three different ports, you will have to start *three* Wildfly instances with port offset:

```
bin/standalon.sh -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100 
bin/standalon.sh -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=200
bin/standalon.sh -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=300
```

In this case you have:

- port 8080 -> first application
- port 8180 -> second application
- port 8280 -> third application

Comment: that is what i did, however there is only one listener on latest port the wildfly instance started to using exactly the same commands, i start wildfly from intellij btw

Comment: You will also need three copies of Wildfly (i.e. three different folders in your file system). Do not start Wildfly in this case from your IDE but from command line.